# Where do all the language files come from under wp-content/languages/plugins

Tags: wordpress

I installed Loco Translate and Polylang. But I'm not sure which plugins were the ones putting the language files under wp-content/languages/plugins.

Are these language files save to delete cos I dont need Loco Translate or Polylang anymore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1LMW.png)

Comment: can you please say your requirments clearly

Comment: I just updated my question

Answer (score 0):

What you talking about are .po files
Try going to Loco Translate -> Themes/ or Plugins, add/edit a translation and you can see all the translations there

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I found out. The po and mo files were created by Polylang plugin